# What is the meaning of the idiom, "limbing forth to the life"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-meaning

I've come across what appears to be an idiom that I'm at a loss as to the meaning, and searched online to no avail. The text is [Dæmonologie and Theologie](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/a86498.0001.001?rgn=main;view=fulltext) by Nathanael Homes, published in 1650.

> …a most exact pourtracture of a Crucifix, **limbing forth to the life**… (p. 18)

> And we finde it true by many experiences, that all men as they use different Arts or wayes, dream differently; which Claudian the Poet **limbs out to the life**; thus… (p. 95)

> O what a lively Iconisme and Character is this of these times; **limbing forth to the life**, the hereticall impious persons thereof… (p. 201)

Does anyone have an idea, or seen this idiom used elsewhere?

Comment: A limner is a type of painter (see https://www.thefreedictionary.com/limner). The modern verb is *limn*; but *limb* may be an old spelling.

Comment: @Peter 'limn' seems to come from illumine. Which does not explain the OPs question.

Comment: @Peter that actually appears to be the case, thank you, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears *limb* is either a copyist error, or a variant spelling of the word *limn*.

Upon further investigation I found in *Polygraphice* by William Salmon (published in 1673) what appears to be an explicit definition not only of *limning* but also *limning to the life*:

[CHAP. XV. Of Limning, and the Materials thereof](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A60739.0001.001/1:7.15?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)

> **Limning** is an Art whereby in water colours, we strive to resemble nature in every thing **to the life**.

[CHAP. VIII. Of Limning to the life in general](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A60739.0001.001/1:9.8?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)

> First draw it with colours, neatly and **to the life**; then wash it roughly as the rest…

The meaning of *to the life* appears readily available in modern English:

> **to the life** - Showing an exact likeness or resemblance to another person, place, or thing. ([The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+life))

With all things considered, it appears as though *limbing* or *limning to the life* literally means *painting something in a life-like manner*, and figuratively, *to explain or depict* (illuminate). The literal meaning appears to be in use in the first quotation of the OP, and the figurative meaning in the others.